# Not sure how to code insert statement when there is a foreign key in a table for Python 2.7 using SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to read some Twitter data and create a few SQLite tables in Python 2.7.  One of the tables (Tweets) has a foreign key linking to the primary key ID in the User table.  When I run the following program Python gives me this error:     **if tweetDict[key] in ['',[]]:
KeyError: 'UserID_fk1'**

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!

```
import sqlite3, json

conn = sqlite3.connect('Tweets_Database_A6.db')
c = conn.cursor()

localFD = open('alltweets.txt','r')



numLines = 10

createTable1 = '''CREATE TABLE User (
                 ID         NUMBER(20),
                 Name        VARCHAR(75),
                 Screen_name VARCHAR(75),
                 Description VARCHAR(200),
                 Friends_count INTEGER,

                 CONSTRAINT User_PK  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
              );'''

c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User');
c.execute(createTable1)

createTable2 = '''CREATE TABLE Tweets (
                 ID          NUMBER(20),
                 Created_At  DATE,
                 Text        CHAR(141),
                 Source VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
                 In_Reply_to_User_ID NUMBER(20),
                 Retweet_Count NUMBER(10),
                 UserID NUMBER(20),

                 CONSTRAINT Tweets_PK  PRIMARY KEY (id,text),

                 CONSTRAINT fk1_Tweets
                  FOREIGN KEY(UserID)
                   REFERENCES User(ID)


              );'''

c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tweets')
c.execute(createTable2)

def readTweets(localFD, numLines, output = 'C:/Python27/tweettables.txt'):

    if output:
        outFD = open(output, 'w')

    batchRows = 1
    batchedInserts1 = []
    batchedInserts2 = []



    while numLines > 0:
        line = localFD.readline()
        numLines = numLines - 1
        tweetDict = json.loads(line)
        userDict = tweetDict['user']

        newRow1 = [] 
        newRow2 = []
        tweetKeys = ['id','created_at','text','source','in_reply_to_user_id','retweet_count','UserID_fk1']
        userKeys = ['id','name','screen_name','description','friends_count']

        for key in userKeys:
            if userDict[key] in ['',[]]:
                  newRow1.append(None)
            else:
                  newRow1.append(userDict[key])

        batchedInserts1.append(newRow1)

        for key in tweetKeys:
            if tweetDict[key] in ['',[]]:
                newRow2.append(None)
            else:
                newRow2.append(tweetDict[key])

        batchedInserts2.append(newRow2)


        if len(batchedInserts2) >= batchRows or numLines == 0:
            c.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO User VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)', batchedInserts1)
            c.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Tweets VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', batchedInserts2)
            batchedInserts1 = []
            batchedInserts2 = []


        if output:
            outFD.write(line)

    if output:
        outFD.close()


readTweets(localFD, numLines)

localFD.close()
c.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

the data you are loading from 'C:/Python27/tweettables.txt' and storing in `tweetDict` does not contain a value for 'UserID_fk1' - the error says exactly what is wrong.

this isn't a python or a sqlite issue, you simply don't have that information in the data you read.

maybe what you mean to have, instead of

```
if tweetDict[key] in ['',[]]:
```

is

```
if key not in tweetDict:
```

then `None` would be inserted instead.

if that's no help you really need to add some of the data to your question.